# Expression Blend, Button states, how to?

Tags: button, expression-blend, states, expression-blend-4

Sorry for such a rudimentary question, but I am not experienced in Blend 4 much at all.

What I need to do, and based on the little I know or have seen it seems that Blend is the place to do it, is to create a "state" for a button to appear when it is disabled.  i.e., the button I'm working with is a Sign Out button...the button IsEnabled property is bound to the WebContext.User.IsAuthenticated property.  So, when the app is loading I want the button's "disabled state (<-- created in Blend?) to appear...once authentication is completed, the binding to IsEnabled will change, and I want the button's "enabled state" to kick in.  How to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what XAML code you have now?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks extremely similar to an issue I was having the other day.

If you go to this thread you may be able to use that as a solution:  [Expression Blend Interaction: How to set Trigger to Look for IsEnabled Value of Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084149/expression-blend-interaction-how-to-set-trigger-to-look-for-isenabled-value-of-b)

I have a Boolean value there called "IsSavedAllowedBool".  You would want to replace that with whatever bool you are binding to - which looks as if it might be WebContext.User.IsAuthenticated.